# Magento 2 controller execute only executing once when cache enabled

Tags: magento2, controllers

```
class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{    
    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(Context $context, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {        
         $this->logger = $logger;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
     public function execute()
    { 
          $this->logger->addDebug("TEST");
    }
}
```

In Magento 1 the controller action executes always when we go to the corresponding url. But in magento 2 "Test" gets logged only when i clear my cache and go to the controller url otherwise it doesn't. How can i add it to a controller in magento 2 so that it will keep on executing the code when i go to the corresponding url, without clearing the cache, like magento 1.

Comment: i faced same issue here.can u tell me what is the solution.i override catalog product view controller

Comment: I'm really sorry i also couldn't figure out the exact issue. I created a new controller and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code by

```
$this->logger->debug("TEST");
```

Comment: Tried. Still it only prints if i clear my cache. Seems like the execute method gets executed if the cache is cleared.

Comment: which version you tried? It's work with M2.10, M2.0.5

Comment: I tried with Magento community edition 2.1. I think it's happening because of the magento full page cache.

Comment: May be, But I tested enable/disable cache both.

Comment: I created another controller and tried and it started working. The previous controller was returning $this->pageFactory->create(). Don't know why it didn't work.